# web3.toAscii for foreign languages

Tags: web3js, string, bytes32, hex

I have a function that takes `bytes32 _name` as a parameter and store it in a struct.

Let's say `_name` is either Chinese, Korean, or Japanese and from `app.js` I would convert the `_name` to hex to pass it to the function.

```
App.contracts.Test.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            return instance.storeName(web3.toHex(name), { from: account });
```

Now, when I retrieve the `name` by calling the function and convert it  using `web3.toAscii`

```
App.contracts.Test.deployed().then(function(instance) {                 
        return instance.getStruct.call();
    }).then(function(result) {
```

`var name = web3.toAscii(result[1]);`

the value would look like `ÁÁ8È`. Is it something that `web3.toAscii` cannot handle other languages or should I just use `string _name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red flag here is of course that you are using `web3.toAscii` to convert Chinese, Korean, etc. [Ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) by default is restricted to the English language.

Solidity supports utf-8 and yes you can get and read names which are in utf-8 encoding (which allows non-English characters). The solution is to encode into utf-8 and then rest is all covered by `web3`.

`var chinese_string = '你好'; //hello
var chinese_string_utf_encoded = '\xE4\xBD\xA0\xE5\xA5\xBD'; //checkout utf-8js`

`web3.toHex(a_utf_encoded); //returns "0xe4bda0e5a5bd"`

Now use `web3.toUtf8` to decode it back to the original Chinese text.

`web3.toUtf8("0xe4bda0e5a5bd"); //returns "你好"`